# How can I validate QR code based on ID from Firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am developing an Ionic 4 app that should scan and validate QR code for claiming, using PhoneGap Plugin BarcodeScanner. The scanning is working as expected but I'm having difficulties on validating the QR code.

My idea is that the QR code is only valid for the user if the userID and PromotionID matches the QR Code (in Firestore database). I'm using the document ID's to generate QR code For example, QR code '
075u6SGzsZ3tWq1v3Trb
' and '
XXDzN47QXqsGZIMeySw0
' can only be use by user123.
[image: Firestore example]

Below is the implementation

Example.page.ts:

```
 qr: any;

scanQRCode () {
  this.options= {
  preferFrontCamera : false, 
  showFlipCameraButton : true, 
  showTorchButton:true,
  disableSuccessBeep: false,
  torchOn: false,
  prompt: 'Scan your QRcode'
};
this.subscription = this.afs.collection('claims')
 .snapshotChanges()
 .subscribe(data => {

  this.qr= data.map(e => {
    return {
      id: e.payload.doc.id,
      promotionID: e.payload.doc.data()['promotion'],
      userID: e.payload.doc.data()['user'],
    };
  })
  console.log(this.item);
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
});

    this.scanner.scan(this.options).then((data) => {
      this.scannedData = data;
      if(this.qr.promotionID && this.qr.userID == data){
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/nextPage');
    }else{
      return this.presentAlert('Error','Invalid QRCODE')
    }

  }, (err) => {
  console.log('Error: ',err);
 })
}
```

Example.page.html

```
<ion-button expand="block" icon-left (click)="scanQRCode()"><ion-icon name="qr-scanner"></ion-icon>Scan code</ion-button>
```

I am new to Ionic and firebase, any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you able to scan and read the QR code if its not valid?

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of issues with this.

You define the scanner options and don't pass them to `scan()`:

```
this.options= {
  preferFrontCamera : true, 
  showFlipCameraButton : true, 
  showTorchButton:true,
  disableSuccessBeep: false,
  torchOn: false,
  prompt: 'Scan your QRcode'
};
this.scanner.scan(this.options).then((data) => {
```

You `.subscribe()` but don't list an `.unsubscribe()`, which means there is a memory leak.

You don't call `getUser()` anywhere in what you have posted - is `this.claim` null?

When you are checking if you should redirect to the results page it doesn't test `this.scannedData` after you have scanned it, it just compares two parts of your user with `this.claim.claimuser == this.claim.promoid`.

Of the parts that you are trying to compare, `claim.claimuser` will never exist because you map it to `claim.user`.

It really needs starting again I think, sorry.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code, please take a look. The compares part always return 'Invalid QRCODE'. Is there any other way to compare to get the correct result? I'm thinking of using query `equalTo()`, but not sure how. Please be gentle as I'm new to this. :)